# how can i invoke a synchronous call in typescript like invoke a call based on response

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Here the first service post method returned some response afterwards the second service Get method need to call like synchronously via flatMap its working fine but after a day when i refresh my page or when the service invoked i got the error. Here i attached that error, can any one help me out this.

```
 return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + routeUrl, data, { headers: headers })
     .flatMap(tokenResult =>
       this.http.get(this.baseUrl + route, { headers: 
       DataService.getHeaderWithToken(tokenResult) })
       .map(res => {
           return res.json()
       })
    );
```

[TypeError: this.http.post(...).flatMap is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIoJo.png)

Comment: The image is missing.

Comment: Here this is my error: TypeError: this.http.post(...).flatMap is not a function

Comment: Hope you have included rxjs in those service class.

Comment: Yes, I already done